# Concat object array based on keys javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, knockout.js

I have an arrays like below

```
{
    "key1": [
        { "prop1": "26181712", "prop2": "2618112" },
        { "prop1": "26181734", "prop2": "2618144" }
    ],
    "Key2": [
        { "prop1": "2618174", "prop2": "2618542" }
    ]
}
```

Expected result is like below.

```
[
    { "key": "key1", "prop1": "26181712", "prop2": "2618112" },
    { "key": "key1", "prop1": "26181734", "prop2": "2618144" },
    { "key": "Key2", "prop1": "2618174", "prop2": "2618542" }
]
```

I am not very good at arrays methods. This seems like reverse to reduce. It can be achieved by for loop but i'd like know better/efficient way to do this with simple/less/es6 code.

Comment: if you can do it with loop, please share the code , i will convert it to array methods for you. please let me know what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand out key, map inner array with {key} merged, flatten

```js
data={
    "key1": [
        { "prop1": "26181712", "prop2": "2618112" },
        { "prop1": "26181734", "prop2": "2618144" }
    ],
    "Key2": [
        { "prop1": "2618174", "prop2": "2618542" }
    ]
}
console.log(
Object.entries(data).flatMap(([key,v])=>v.map(x=>({key, ...x})))
)
```

Comment: props for neater and shorter code.

Comment: you could even short it more by using a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) of `key` instead of `k`.

Answer (score 1):

You loop over your keys, on every key-value you map it and add an new property to it `key`.

Because thats an array you can use spread operator to spread it into the `result` array.

```js
let data = {
    "key1": [
        { "prop1": "26181712", "prop2": "2618112" },
        { "prop1": "26181734", "prop2": "2618144" }
    ],
    "Key2": [
        { "prop1": "2618174", "prop2": "2618542" }
    ]
}


let result = [];
for(let prop in data){ 
   let item = data[prop].map(el => ({key: prop, ...el}))
   result = [...result, ...item] 
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way with nested map & flat.

```
const data = {
    "key1": [
        { "prop1": "26181712", "prop2": "2618112" },
        { "prop1": "26181734", "prop2": "2618144" }
    ],
    "Key2": [
        { "prop1": "2618174", "prop2": "2618542" }
    ]
};

console.log(
  Object.keys(data).map(i => data[i].map(j => (Object.assign({'key': i}, j)))).flat()
);
```

Comment: To be honest, i like @user120242 answer above., much easier to read.,